Cycles render part of my background image and leave the rest blank
When I Render my Background layer, it only renders 3/4 of my background image. (I put some cubes there for better understanding)
The UV map is good, no camera clipping, I also tried tiling, scaling down the image (its a plane with a cloth sim.) but nothing seems to work and it always cuts the image.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Looks like you have enabled Holdout for objects or collections. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up/260472#260472 Or maybe you are speaking about render border. Disable "Render region" in output settings

@Crantisz I am talking about the black line at the top of the picture, which is completely black. I put some random cubes there to show the area, the rest of the image is indented.
Disabling Render Region does not affect the result.

@Jakemoyo Yes here is the file (just the background because of size)

I used Blender v4.0 (Octane Edition(because it was my only 4.0 version I still had))
